# Eclipse Auto code completion

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

As we need to press Ctrl+Space to see the auto-code which are guessed by Eclipse, is there any setting by which this words of codes will be automaticaly shown by Eclipse and we don't need to press Ctrl+Space every time, like Xcode for example.

Sorry for english :(

Comment: What computer language?

Answer (score 0):

If you open up Eclipse preferences and type "Content Assist" into the search box you can configure the auto-activation delay and auto-activation triggers for the different languages.

Comment: but still in need to press Ctrl+Space.is there are setting anywhere in eclipse by which those guesses comes automatically.

Comment: Are you in the java perspective? (Windows > Open Perspective > Java) In my eclipse as soon as I type "." the content assist comes up.

Comment: yup, it comes but while i typing class name,variable name and pressing ctrl+space gives me content assist this is should also comes up automatically.If you used xcode then you should understand what i exactly saying :)

Comment: Ah yes. The way xcode does content assist is nice, unfortunately I don't believe you can get eclipse to work the same way.

Comment: I think this question might be helpful for me
 stackoverflow.com/questions/3758205/is-there-eclipse-useful-add-on-for-autocomplete-function-like-xcode